# Keep in a Graph only those edges in a list

Tags: python, networkx

I have this list of edges (tuples) called edgesKeep that I want to KEEP in the graph, and remove all other edges. In my case (because of how edgesKeep is built), there is no guarantee that the node names in edges of edgesKeep follow the same order of node names in G.edges (an edge can be `('u','v')` in one and appear as `('v','u')` in the other one). So I have to do this:

```
G.remove_edges_from(e for e in G.edges if e not in edgesKeep and tuple(reversed(e)) not in edgesKeep)
```

Is there a way to make it simpler? I mean, somehow getting rid of `tuple(reversed(e)) not in edgesKeep` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the tuples in `edgesKeep` and do

```py
G.remove_edges_from(e for e in G.edges if sorted(e) not in edgesKeep)
```